# Upgrading kube-prometheus-stack via Helm to chart v56.2.1 fails on Grafana with Sensitive key error

Tags: kubernetes, prometheus, kubernetes-helm, grafana, kube-prometheus-stack

I recently tried upgrading kube-prometheus-stack on my AWS EKS Kubernetes cluster via Helm to chart `v56.2.1` using Terraform and it failed while upgrading Grafana with the following error:

`Sensitive key ‘auth.generic_oauth.client_secret’ should not be defined explicitly in values. Use variable expansion instead.`

I'm not specifying any client_secret via `values.yml` file for that Helm chart but we are using AzureAD for authentication.

How to fix this?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

There are 2 possible solutions to fix this issue:

1. Set `grafana.assertNoLeakedSecrets` to `false` in the `values.yml` file.
2. If `auth.generic.oauth.client_secret` is specified in the `values.yml` file, remove it from that file and set `GF_AUTH_GENERIC_OAUTH_CLIENT_SECRET` as the environment variable for Grafana.

References:

- [Grafana - Sensitive Key Known Issue](https://picluster.ricsanfre.com/docs/prometheus/#:%7E:text=configuration%3A%20step%203.-,Important%3A,-In%20new%20versions)
- [Grafana - Override configuration with environment variables](https://grafana.com/docs/grafana/latest/setup-grafana/configure-grafana/#override-configuration-with-environment-variables)

Comment: Use `GF_AUTH_AZUREAD_CLIENT_SECRET` if encountering `'auth.azuread.client_secret' should not be defined explicitly ...`

Comment: How do you set `GF_AUTH_GENERIC_OAUTH_CLIENT_SECRET` as env variable in Terraform?

Comment: @AniketKariya That depends on how you're creating it via Terraform. If it is a helm chart, you need to find the variable to be updated in the values file. You can update either the environment variables or the config map or the secrets. You can see this for reference: https://registry.terraform.io/providers/hashicorp/helm/latest/docs/resources/release 
Another approach can be found here: https://xebia.com/blog/deploying-grafana-to-azure-app-service-with-terraform-and-active-directory-integration/

Answer (score 0):

```hcl
resource "kubernetes_secret" "grafana" {
  ...
  data = {
    "GF_AUTH_GENERIC_OAUTH_CLIENT_SECRET" = var.auth_generic_oauth_client_secret
  }
}


resource "helm_release" "kube_prometheus_stack" {
  chart = "kube-prometheus-stack"
  ...
  set {
    name  = "grafana.envFromSecret"
    value = kubernetes_secret.grafana.metadata[0].name
  }
}
```

Grafana's Helm chart provides multiple ways to securely mount environment variables: `envFromSecret`, `envRenderSecret`, `envFromSecrets`, `envFromConfigMaps`, and `extraSecretMounts`. You can find more information at [charts/grafana/values.yaml](https://github.com/grafana/helm-charts/blob/main/charts/grafana/values.yaml#L486).

The variable name is in the format pf `GF_<SectionName>_<KeyName>`. As described at [grafana/variable-expansion](https://grafana.com/docs/grafana/latest/setup-grafana/configure-grafana/#variable-expansion). So:

```ini
[auth.google]
client_secret = ...
```

becomes `GF_AUTH_GOOGLE_CLIENT_SECRET`. Any env variable set will by default override the value if also defined in the `grafana.ini`. If you would like to use the `$__file` provider, you can use the `extraSecretMounts` and set the following helm values:

```hcl
resource "kubernetes_secret" "auth_generic_oauth_secret" {
  ...
  metadata {
    name = "auth-generic-oauth-secret"
  }
  data = {
    "client_id" = "......"
    "client_secret" = "......."
  }
}

resource "helm_release" "kube_prometheus_stack" {
  ...
  set { 
    name  = "grafana.extraSecretMounts[0].name"
    value = "auth-generic-oauth-secret-mount"
  }
  set {
    name  = "grafana.extraSecretMounts[0].secretName"
    value = kubernetes_secret.auth_generic_oauth_secret.metadata[0].name
  }
  set { 
    name  = "grafana.extraSecretMounts[0].defaultMode"
    value = 0440
  }
  set { 
    name  = "grafana.extraSecretMounts[0].mountPath"
    value = "/etc/secrets/auth_generic_oauth"
  }
  set {
    name  = "grafana.extraSecretMounts[0].readOnly"
    value = true
  }
}
```

Now that the secret is mounted as a file, we can use the `$__file` provider to set the credentials:

```hcl
  set {
    name = "grafana.grafana\\.ini.auth.generic_oauth.client_id"
    value = "$__file{/etc/secrets/auth_generic_oauth/client_id}"
  }
  set {
    name = "grafana.grafana\\.ini.auth.generic_oauth.client_secret"
    value = "$__file{/etc/secrets/auth_generic_oauth/client_secret}"
  }
```